# create a namespace in c++/cli?

Tags: c#, namespaces, c++-cli

I have seen many examples of `using` .NET Framework namespaces in c++/cli like the following:

```
using namespace System;
using namespace System::IO;
```

But I haven't seen any examples of creating my own. So I was wondering if there is a way to declare/create my own namespace as I would in C#:

```
namespace Animals
   {

   public class Dog
       {
       public Dog() {}
       }
   }
```

Thanks for your time :)

Comment: Create a Winforms app to see an example.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Same syntax for single namespaces.  Nest for multiples, e.g. for First.Second.Third:

```
namespace First
{
namespace Second
{
namespace Third
{

    // Your code

}
}
}
```

In C# the same would be:

```
namespace First.Second.Third
{
}
```

Comment: I'm having difficulty with this now.. I created a new question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6696598/namespace-not-recognized-in-c-cli. Would you be able to give any insight?

Comment: I would assume that your issue is that the class Dog isn't found.  That's not because of the namespace or because of C++/CLI, it's because you're using C++ without proper headers.  You need to define classes in a header file before they can be used elsewhere in C++ or in C++/CLI.  Either one is the same.

Answer (score 2):

You already know how it should be done, as is demonstrated by your example

```
namespace NamespaceName //C++/CLI or C#
{
    //contents
}
```

Comment: um.. it's sort of different syntax etc. and like I said I haven't seen it done anywhere..

Comment: @developer: It's the same syntax :)