# Namespace not recognized in C++/CLI

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2010, namespaces, c++-cli

I asked this question recently: [create a namespace in c++/cli?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6681175/create-a-namespace-in-c-cli)
and so I am trying to create my own namespace in c++/cli.

But when I use the same namespace in two separate files (.cpp), the namespace is clearly not recognized as being the same because I get errors when I try to reference the other class in the other file.

Here's basically what I have:

Pets.cpp:

```
namespace Animals
   {
   public ref class Pets 
     {
     public:
        List<Dog> ^vDogs;

     Pets::Pets()
        {
        vDogs = gcnew List<Dog^>();
        }

     void Pets::DoSomething()
        {
        }
     };
   }
```

Dog.cpp:

```
namespace Animals
   {
   public ref class Dog 
     {

     Dog::Dog()
        {
        }

     void Dog::DoSomething()
        {
        }
     };
   }
```

Other information:

1) Files are in the *same* folder

2) Files were added to an existing solution in a *different* folder

3) I also tried `using namespace Animals` in either file but I get an error saying namespace does not exist.

4) I am using Visual Studio 2010 (fyi in case someone has a way to fix but I need to do something specific in VS)

So my question is: What do I need to do in order for the namespace to be recognized?

Please let me know what other information is needed in order for the problem to be solved.

Thanks in advance for your time and patience! :)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The C++/CLI compiler is stuck with the build model of traditional C and C++ compilers.  Formulated at a time when a kilobyte of memory took as much space as a shoebox.  It is a single-pass compiler that processes one .cpp file at a time.  With a linker to glue the bits together.

Which means that you'll have to use traditional header files to declare your classes and the #include directive at the top of your source code file to include it.

Comment: Ok, so I will try to switch to the header file.. though I am wary due to problems I had in the past with putting `public ref class Pets{}` in the header file (compiler didn't seem to like it.. which is why it's in the cpp now) - any insight on this is welcome! :)

Comment: I don't know what that means.  Have you considered reading a book about C++/CLI programming rather than trying this somewhat randomly?

Comment: Retry as Hans told (= put declaration/definition in the header). Remember to just include the header in one cpp file. At this point, you can safely restart from a clean project. When you use the dll in another clr/cil project remember to add it as a reference. And remember: C++/CLI is **NOT** recommended for a new project. No value added by the fact you already know C++. C++/CLI is only recommended to wrap native code. If you don't need to wrap native code, just go C#.

Comment: No time to read a book on it.. need to wrap native code on strict deadline.

Comment: I reread your answer, and I'm wondering.. do you mean that I cannot create a namespace in the header file? The answers to my previous question stated I could.. :s

Comment: No, that's not what it means.  I can't really guess why you drew that conclusion.

Comment: You stated I must use the #include directive (which is obvious), but you did not mention anything about namespaces.. so it seemed that perhaps you meant the only way to reference other classes was to use the include statement.