# Problem creating managed classes and namespaces in C++/CLI

Tags: c#, namespaces, c++-cli

I am having problems creating a managed class with namespace in C++/CLI.

I would like to do the following:

```
#pragma once
#include "abc.h"
#ifdef _MANAGED
#using <system.dll>
using namespace System;
using namespace System::IO;
using namespace System::Collections::Generic;
using namespace System::Globalization;
#endif

namespace Animals
    {
    public ref class Pets
        {
        Pets::Pets(){}
        };
    }
```

I have a couple different problems:

A) When I place this code into the .cpp file, it compiles fine. However, it appears the namespaces are not working as expected (see this question I created: [Namespace not recognized in C++/CLI](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6696598/namespace-not-recognized-in-c-cli)) The only answer listed says I must declare the classes/namespaces in the header file. But this is a problem because..

B) The compiler complains about `public ref class Pets` when it is placed in the header file. It says there must be a syntax error.

intellisense error:

`expected a declaration`

other errors:

`'{' : missing function header (old-style formal list?)`

`syntax error: 'public'`

I can't seem to find any great C++/CLI examples that show both the header and the cpp file.

**So my question is: How can I make both the managed class and namespace work as expected? (i.e. what am I doing wrong?)**

Please let me know if I need to include any more information.

Thanks in advance for your time and patience :)

Comment: Please give your header file, too. it may only contain forward declarations.

Comment: @marc: I've just moved the above code in and out of the header. (no additional code used to show you).

Comment: what is the exact error you get?

Comment: @marc: updated question as per your request

Comment: you should just do a forward declaration in your header. so omit the `{}` behind `Pets::Pets()`` and place a `;` there in the header.

Comment: Checking `#ifdef _MANAGED` is pretty pointless, since you use C++/CLI-only keywords such as `ref class`.

Comment: @Ben Voigt: well.. I probably won't be doing *just* that in the file in the near future...

Comment: @developer: What I meant is that you're using `ref class` outside the `#ifdef` region, so the file won't compile right without `/clr`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In the header file there should just be forward declarations.

```
// abc.h
#pragma once

namespace Animals
{
    public ref class Pets
    {
        Pets(); // forward declaration
        // Pets::Pets is redundant and wrong, because you are inside 
        // the class Pets
    };
}


// abc.cpp
#include "abc.h"
#ifdef _MANAGED
#using <system.dll>
using namespace System;
using namespace System::IO;
using namespace System::Collections::Generic;
using namespace System::Globalization;
#endif

namespace Animals
{
    Pets::Pets() {}  // implementation
    // Now Pets::Pets() is right, because you dont write the class... wrapper again.
}
```